# How to suppress warnings in third-party source files?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, keil

I am familiar with warning suppressing pragmas for GCC and Keil (they are different, but the usage is pretty much the same).
For a third-party headers I can do something like this:

```
#pragma push
#pragma suppress warning
#include "whatever.h"
#pragma pop
```

But how can I suppress warnings from third-party sources? Both Eclipse+GCC and Keil generate them.
The only solution I came up is making whapper .c-file, which will **include other .c files**, which seems to be very dirty trick.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: If you'd have one well-named & set-apart further empty source file including the third party one, I'd call this a "trick", and not a "very dirty trick".  Matter of taste of course :-)  I do agree that a more 'standard' solution is highly preferable.

Comment: These trick will be also a bit inconvenient for Eclipse, coz eclipse by default includes all files in project folder in the build process. So this third-party sources will be built twice - one as themselves and another one as included. Of course, they can be manually excluded from built, but that's another pain.

Answer (score 4):

with **gcc** , while compiling you can use **-w** option to suppress warnings.

**-w : Inhibit all warning messages.**

Example:

```
gcc -w third_party_sourcefile.c
```

Comment: That's a good way, but I'm not sure it will be suitable for Eclipse, since it generates makefiles.

Comment: @Amomum ,Sorry i am not familiar with Eclipse. some one will definitely give you useful info regarding Eclipse also.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `-isystem` instead of `-Idir` third party headers. See [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html).

If you're ok to edit third party source files, you can use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-to-disable"` see [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Comment: Headers are out of question. Also, I'm not sure, how can I do this with Eclipse (since I use it's interface for pointing include directories).